# How to Implement class composition with inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, uml, composition

I am new to object oriented development and appreciate your help in this regard.
In my payroll system, I have four classes called ‘Payment’, ‘Salary’, ‘Earning’ and ‘Deduction’. 
preparing salary requires many types of earnings (like OT, Incentives, Spacial Allowance, payments for extra shifts, budgetary allowances, Brought forward amounts etc.) and deductions (like Insurance, Uniform, Loans,Recovery, Welfare, meals, salary advance taken etc.) 
So I split this in to two classes namely 'Earning' and 'Deduction'. Finally class 'Salary' is supposed to do the balancing part and class 'payment' will handle payment part (banking). Other type of payment is salary advance which is just an amount paid monthly. the relationships modeled, as follows…
‘Earning’ and ‘Deduction’ classes has a composition relationship with ‘Salary’ and ‘Salary’ is a derived class from ‘Payment’. I have implemented these relationships in my C# code as follows…
My questions are

1.Whether I ve related classes in a proper way?

2.Is implementation of the relationships correct?

**PAYMENTS**

```
   class payment
    {
        public virtual void pay()
        {

        }
}
```

**SALARY**

```
class salary:payment
{
//Composition of ‘Earning’ class
    private earning E1;

    public salary()
    {
        E1 = new earning(this);

    }
//Calling calEarning() of ‘Earning’ class through ‘Salary’ class
    public void calEarningForSal()
    {
        E1.calEarning();
    }

//Implementing pay method of base class 
    public override void pay()
    {

    }
```

}

**EARNING**

```
  public class earning
    {
    //Since earning has a composition relationship with salary…
        private salary S1;

        internal earning(salary sal)
        {
            this.S1 = sal;
        }
    //This method will calculate earnings of employees
        public void calEarning()
        {

        }
    }
```

**MAIN METHOD**

```
Main()
        {
            salary newSal = new salary();
            newSal.calEarningForSal();
        }
```

Comment: It depends on what you want. As usual. I don't get the intended role of 'earning' and 'deduction' here.

Comment: But Salary IS-A payment sounds doubtful. What if a salary is payed in 2 parts?

Comment: I agree with @HenkHolterman, I started to answer this then realised the ambiguity between a `Salary` and an `Earning` - you need to clarify each classes role.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, Actually in this case, preparing salary requires  many types of earnings (like OT, Incentives, Spacial Allowance, payments for extra shifts, budgetary allowances, Brought forward amounts etc.) and deductions (like Insurance, Uniform, Loans,Recovery, Welfare, meals, salary advance taken etc.) So I split this in to two classes namely 'Earning' and 'Deduction'. Finally class 'Salary' is supposed to do the balancing part and class 'payment' will handle payment part (banking). Other type of payment is salary advance which is just an amount paid monthly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When trying to work out whether to use Composition or Aggregation the simple question to ask is

- Does A *belong* to B
- Does A *use* B

In your case, you state

> ‘Earning’ and ‘Deduction’ classes has a composition relationship with ‘Salary’

So in layman's terms, what you are saying is `Earning`/`Deduction`*belong to* a `Salary`, in other words, a `Salary` is *made up of* an `Earning`/`Deduction` (and however many other components). With that being said, I would expect your `Salary` class to look something like

```
public class Salary
{
    private Earning e;
    private Deduction d;

    public Salary()
    {
        this.e = new Earning();
        this.d = new Deduction();
    }

    public void override Pay()
    {
        ... 
    }
}
```

`Earning`/`Deduction` should not know about `Salary`, these classes are effectively components which make up what a `Salary` is. For example, your `Earning` class might look like

```
public class Earning
{
    public Earning()
    {
    }

    public void Calculate()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If `Earning`/`Deduction` need information *from* `Salary` then you can pass this information down, however, you should not pass a reference to `Salary` itself because that will break the composition relationship (and infact introduce aggregation between `Earning`/`Salary`).

---

On the inheritance stuff, if the base class `Payment` doesn't offer any more than a simple `Pay` method then I would recommend using an interface instead e.g.

```
public interface IPayable
{
    void Pay();
}

public class Salary : IPayable
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sir, Actually Payment class has few more methods like, makeSummary(), viewPayment(), viewPaymentHistory(), bank() etc. Kindly look at the comment given to @Henk Holterman for more details. Thanks!

Comment: @Chathur that's fine, you don't need to use the interface suggestion. If a `Salary` is actually made up of *multiples* of  `Earning`/`Deduction` then I would just maintain an internal list for both - it still wouldn't make sense to pass `Salary` into  `Earning`/`Deduction`.